# Xml-сериализация атрибутов вложенных узлов в свойства объекта

Tags: c#, xml, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность десериализовать Xml-элемент подобной структуры:

```
  <Service>
    <Host value="http://domain.com:80" />
    <Username value="user_name" />
    <Password value="password" />
  </Service>
```

в объект примерно такого класса:

```
[XmlRoot("Service")]
public class Service
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

То есть смысл в том, чтобы не создавать для каждого вложенного узла свой класс, наподобие этого:

```
public class Host
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

и затем не городить огород:

```
[XmlRoot("Service")]
public class Service
{
    [XmlElement("Host")]
    public Host Host { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

...

var host = service.Host.Value;
```

Хочется верить, что атрибуты "value" всех вложенных узлов можно сразу замапить на string-свойства. Буду благодарен за любой совет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть, пусть Service имплементирует интерфейс IXmlSerializable и реализует ReadXml разумным образом?

Сделать это только при помощи атрибутов невозможно: свойства определяют либо такой:

```
<Service>
    <Host>http://domain.com:80</Host>
    <Username>user_name</Username>
    <Password>password</Password>
</Service>
```

либо такой

```
<Service Host="http://domain.com:80"
         Username="user_name"
         Password="password"/>
```

синтаксис.

Я тут набросал код:

```
[XmlRoot]
class Service : IXmlSerializable
{
    string Host;
    string Username;
    string Password;

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement) // проверяем формат
            throw new Exception(); // надо какое-то другое исключение, конечно
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // читаем открывающий тег Service
        while (reader.IsStartElement()) // пока есть вложенные теги...
            processNode(reader);   // читаем их
        reader.ReadEndElement();   // читаем закрывающий тег
    }

    void processNode(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) // опять проверяем формат
            throw new Exception();
        if (reader.AttributeCount != 1) // то же самое
            throw new Exception();
        string name = reader.Name;
        string value = reader.GetAttribute(0);
        setField(name, value);
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // переходим к следующему
    }

    void setField(string name, string value)
    {
        switch (name) // ну или reflection, если хотите
        {
        case "Host": Host = value; break;
        case "Username": Username = value; break;
        case "Password": Password = value; break;
        }
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        serializeField(writer, "Host", Host);
        serializeField(writer, "Username", Username);
        serializeField(writer, "Password", Password);
    }

    void serializeField(XmlWriter writer, string name, string value)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(name);
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Value");
        writer.WriteString(value);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

}
```